# Don't display images in ASPxLabel

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have an ASPxLabel with html marks in the text.

`<a href="~/default.aspx" title="Close"><span class="icon-plus-sign"></span> <dxe:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabelTitulo2" EncodeHtml="false" runat="server" Text=""></dxe:ASPxLabel> </a>`
I'm using EncodeHtml to show the style of the text, but the source string from where I get the text can sometimes have images, and I don't want them to show.

I get the text value from a datatable, obviously it has html marks.

`ASPxLabelTitulo2.Text = dtFAQ.Rows[1]["Question"].ToString();`

Thank you for the help, please let me know if my english is hard to understand.

I tried to look for a method in ASPxLabel that could customize the style of the text, but I can't find it. I also looked on stackoverflow, but no help either.

Comment: label control will display all in-line HTML - including that of images. Use a text box, that will NOT allow images and the markup. However, the text box will probably show the in-line base64 image that is probably your issue. If you want to strip out the image and junk, then you have to write some code to do this.

Comment: Please describe a format of your image data (at least a text representation)